# How to install and scrape metric for Nginx and mssql in prometheus

Tags: sql-server, nginx, prometheus, grafana, digital-ocean

I am trying to setup prometheus monitoring tool for a project. While I am able to configure prometheus to scrape server metrics with node_exporter and DNS with blackbox_exporter, I am having a hard time setting up metrics for Nginx and MsSQL in prometheus. I will appreciate any resources or walk through to get the exporter for both as well as the installation process for prometheus to scrape data. The project is hosted on digital ocean cloud.

Comment: Thank @DazWilkin. Can you kindly breakdown the process like for a 5year to follow. I still am having difficulty following the outline process.

Comment: I got this error while using the docker install command 
"/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/9e0d9809d2e579ff7e459fcad5dea34db8047b73fc921a65905ca0601da7cdd2/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.

And when I CURL it I got the response below
 curl \
> --request GET \
> http://localhost/basic_status
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

Both appear straightforward:

1. The [NGINX exporter](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter)
2. The **official** [Microsoft SQL Server exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter)

Please update your question and explain:

- Exactly what you tried (include code and config)
- What errors you received

##### Example

This would be better under e.g. Docker Compose but...

`nginx.conf`:

```
events {
    use           epoll;
    worker_connections  128;
}

http {
    server {
        location = /basic_status {
                stub_status;
        }
    }
}
```

Run NGINX (defaults to `:80`):

```sh
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--net=host \
--volume=${PWD}/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro \
nginx
```

Test it:

```sh
curl \
--request GET \
http://localhost/basic_status
```

Run Exporter:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--net=host \
nginx/nginx-prometheus-exporter \
  -nginx.scrape-uri=http://localhost/basic_status
```

Test it:

```sh
curl \
--request GET \
http://localhost:9113/metrics
```

Yields:

```
# HELP nginx_connections_accepted Accepted client connections
# TYPE nginx_connections_accepted counter
nginx_connections_accepted 1
# HELP nginx_connections_active Active client connections
# TYPE nginx_connections_active gauge
nginx_connections_active 1
# HELP nginx_connections_handled Handled client connections
# TYPE nginx_connections_handled counter
nginx_connections_handled 1
# HELP nginx_connections_reading Connections where NGINX is reading the request header
# TYPE nginx_connections_reading gauge
nginx_connections_reading 0
# HELP nginx_connections_waiting Idle client connections
# TYPE nginx_connections_waiting gauge
nginx_connections_waiting 0
# HELP nginx_connections_writing Connections where NGINX is writing the response back to the client
# TYPE nginx_connections_writing gauge
nginx_connections_writing 1
# HELP nginx_http_requests_total Total http requests
# TYPE nginx_http_requests_total counter
nginx_http_requests_total 2
# HELP nginx_up Status of the last metric scrape
# TYPE nginx_up gauge
nginx_up 1
# HELP nginxexporter_build_info Exporter build information
# TYPE nginxexporter_build_info gauge
nginxexporter_build_info{commit="5f88afbd906baae02edfbab4f5715e06d88538a0",date="2021-03-22T20:16:09Z",version="0.9.0"} 1
```

`prometheus.yml`:

```
scrape_configs:
  # Self
  - job_name: "prometheus-server"
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "localhost:9090"

  # NGINX
  - job_name: "nginx"
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "localhost:9113"
```

Then:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--net=host \
--volume=${PWD}/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
prom/prometheus:v2.26.0 \
  --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

Then:

Targets:

[image]

Graph:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dazwilkin. I have gone through the resource you sent but can't comprehend the process. I found a 'docker' in the guide but I am not running one on the server. How do I go about this.
Plus, I am new to the whole installation stuff.

Comment: For the Nginx it was a was not starting having done the process I found on a portal. As for the github you sent, I honestly don't know how to go about it both for the Nginx and MsSQL

Comment: $ sudo $ nginx-prometheus-exporter -nginx.scrape-uri=http://<nginx>:8080/stub_status
-bash: nginx: No such file or directory
$ sudo $ nginx-prometheus-exporter -nginx.scrape-uri=http://143.110.254.3:8080/stub_status $: command not found
$ sudo nginx-prometheus-exporter -nginx.scrape-uri=http://143.110.254.3:8080/stub_status
2021/06/10 18:12:16 Starting NGINX Prometheus Exporter Version=0.7.0 GitCommit=a2910f1
2021/06/10 18:12:16 Could not create Nginx Client: expected 200 response, got 404